# design suggestions for an HTML5-based animated line graph

Tags: html, animation, canvas, svg, flot

I'm planning on developing a scrollable/real-time/animated line graph to run in browsers (using HTML5).  It will be integrated into an app that does some computationally intense stuff (DSP), so I need the graph/animation to be fast and have minimal overhead.  I had created such an app in Silverlight, but because of the limited number of platforms that will support this, I think I'm better off focusing on HTML5, assuming it can be fast enough.

-Any suggestions on whether canvas/svg would be more appropriate, or if there are some existing libraries/apps I might look at?

-Any platform-specific considerations (particularly for mobile/tablet usage)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SVG would be the easiest coding - basically just make the lines in markup and use an object or iframe to open the line graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="300" y2="300"
style="stroke:rgb(99,99,99);stroke-width:2"/>

</svg>
```

The computationally intense stuff can be done on the server and the style can be handled with class just like styles in html.

Limitation of SVG is in the browser support for the animation tag. And SVG is not yet fully supported inline with HTML so you need to treat it like an image.

Canvas requires you to draw the lines with Javascript. Again the computationally intense stuff could be done on the server and the Javascript delivered with only what needs to be drawn. But more time could be needed to do it with canvas.

You can also use script with SVG several examples are here: http://www.carto.net/papers/svg/manipulating_svg_with_dom_ecmascript/

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I won't be able to do any of the work server-side as this will be real-time analysis based on device capture data.

Comment: If javascript in the browser is a must then I would lean toward canvas.